# Table is not mapped - HIBERNATE

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

I have a problem trying to create a query from a Struts2 application with Hibernate and DB2 database. It throws me an Exception:

> Struts Problem Report

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
  Messages:

```
ClienteCRM is not mapped
ClienteCRM is not mapped [FROM ClienteCRM WHERE nombre LIKE XXXX]
```

File:     org/hibernate/hql/internal/ast/util/SessionFactoryHelper.java
  Line number:  171

First of all this is my project tree: 
[image: Project tree]

I have this files:

> Hibernate configuration file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:as400://10.10.10.131/sugarcrmak </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pwd</property>      
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>

    <mapping class="com.ak.exchange.model.dto.ClienteCRM" />
</session-factory>
```

> Bean

```
package com.ak.exchange.model.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="accounts")
//@NamedQuery(name="ClienteCRM.buscarPorNombre", query="from ClienteCRM c where c.nombre like :nombre")
public class ClienteCRM implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="id")
private String id;

@Column(name="name")
private String nombre;

public ClienteCRM(){

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

}

> DAO layer for ClienteCRM

```
package com.ak.exchange.model.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.ak.exchange.model.dto.ClienteCRM;

public class ClienteDAO {
protected Session session;

protected void openSession(){
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}

protected void closeSession(){
    session.close();
}

public List<ClienteCRM> buscarClientesCRMPorNombre (String aNombre){

    this.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

//      Query query = session.getNamedQuery("ClienteCRM.buscarPorNombre");
//      query.setParameter("nombre", "%" + aNombre + "%");

    Query selectAll = session.createQuery("FROM ClienteCRM WHERE nombre LIKE " + aNombre);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<ClienteCRM> tmpClientes = (List<ClienteCRM>) selectAll.list();

    this.closeSession();

    return tmpClientes;
}
```

}

As you can see, I've tried to create a query by using a NamedQuery (commented) and also creating from the DAO.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: First thing I notice is that your NamedQuery syntax is incorrect. You need a select. In your case `select c from ClienteCRM c where c.nombre like :nombre`

Comment: thanks for the correction, i've tried, but it throws me another exception "Named query not known" It seems as Hibernate can't get the mapped classes

Answer (score 0):

- Put your `hibernate.cfg.xml` inside `src/main/resources`
- Put your mapping files inside `src/main/resources`
- Map your files like this: 
   `<mapping resource="ClienteCRM.hbm.xml" />`

It should work.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried but with similar result, It seems as Hibernate can't get the mapped classes, I don't know what i'm doing wrong